# Matplotlib: Plotting more data points than pixels available on screen

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, signal-processing, screen-resolution

I am writting a program which updates a matplotlib plot with 10.000.000-20.000.000 data points (waveform from oscilloscope) every 10sec.

I want to plot the highest possible resolution within the shortest possible time.
The plot does not look really different if I plot all data points or every 1000th, but it updates faster with less data points (~0.3sec execution time with every 1000th point, ~1.5sec with every point).

Since there are more data points than pixels on my screen, matplotlib cannot show all the data points on my screen.

***What are the max. actual diplayed data points on screen with matplotlib?***

***How can I optimize plotting by only displaying as many data points as actually getting displayed on the screen?***

Unfortunately I did not find answers to this on the internet & I would be happy if someone could explain how matplotlib handles this internally, because I do not understand it!

Comment: I would look at the physical values of your plot. Lets say you get values with a resolution of `1e-6 sec` but you are fine with looking at a resolution of `1e-3 sec`, than just use every 1000th point. "Optimizing" on the current screen resolution and than using every 127th point on display A and every 3013th point on display B seems like an overkill.

Comment: I'd be extremely careful just subsampling your data that you don't get aliasing.  You almost certainly want to apply an anti-aliasing filter first or high frequency signals will show up as low-frequency.  Suggest looking at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html